# Estratégia de como salvar imagens (com preview) em CRUD de produtos

Tags: php, javascript, multiple-file-upload

Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com o *upload* de *imagens* de produtos por exemplo: como `linkar` as imagens com o *produto X*, de forma que antes de concluir o cadastro do produto, o usuário possa remover, etc.

E quando à edição, o usuário vai lá, faz todo o "troca-troca" de imagens e acaba **não concluindo a operação**. Qual melhor opção para uma troca de imagens "*Fake*" e que ao voltar para uma nova edição, tudo esteja como antes?

Como exemplo o `MercadoLivre` ou `OLX`. Você cria seu anúncio, adiciona as imagens.. se você ficar indo e voltando as imagens sempre estão sincronizadas.

Comment: Edite sua resposta, adicione a tag `javascript` e coloque o código que está a testar e os possíveis erros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja na imagem abaixo o modelo de Banco de Dados relacional que você precisa usar.

A estratégia seria:
Ao abrir o formulário de adicionar produto você já vai ter que criar um item na tabela produtos com o status que defina que esse produto ainda está em fase de upload. 
A inserção das imagens deve ser feita via Ajax e o relacionamento na tabela já é adicionado ao terminar o upload da imagem.

[Relacionamento entre Produto e Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6negy.png)

Comment: Rafael, era o que eu procurava. Mas me restou uma pequena dúvida. O Status na imagem, para que seria? Para poder controlar se por exemplo, na edição do produto, a imagem irá ser excluída ao termino da operação? Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode usar o status da imagem para controlar o que precisar. Normalmente é melhor usar o status como flag do que deletar o item do banco de dados.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é que você coloque o seu código para facilitar a vida de quem pretende ajudá-lo.

```html
<legend class="leg_img">Insira imagens</legend>
<fieldset id="upload_img" class="nf_class upload_img">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none;" />
    <a href="#" id="fileSelect" >selecionar</a>
    <div id="list" style="margin-bottom:0;"></div>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
var fileElem = document.getElementById("files");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
 fileSelect.style.cssFloat = "right";
 fileSelect.style.marginRight = "3px";
 fileSelect.style.marginTop = "-3px";
 if(fileElem)
 {
  fileElem.click();
 }
 e.preventDefault();
}, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt)
{
 var list = document.getElementById("list").childElementCount;
 var files = evt.target.files;
    var qtde = files.length;
    var nomes = fileElem.files;
    var nome;
     
    if(qtde > 3 || list > 2)
    {
     alert('apenas 3');
     document.getElementById('files').value = ""; 
     return;
    }else
    {
     for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
     {
      if(!f.type.match('image.*'))
      {
          continue;
         }
         var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = (function(theFile)
   {
       return function(e)
       {
           var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.innerHTML = 
 "<a href='#'><img style='float:left;padding: 3px;height: 33px; width: 33px; border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;margin-top: 0px;' src='" + e.target.result + "'" + "title='" + escape(theFile.name) + "'/><img class='icon-del-img' style='float:left;margin-left:-41px;' src='img/icon-del-img.svg'/></a>";
              document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
              span.children[0].addEventListener("click", function(evt)
              {
                  span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
                 });
          };
      })(f);
         reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        } 
        return true;}
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Me perdoe, mas não pedi código, nem tenho código. Perguntei por dicas de estratégias para o processo. O código postado acima, não responde minha pergunta. Como salvar a imagem, fazer upload, etc, eu já sei. Gostaria de saber "Arquitetura Estratégica" para execução da tarefa. Qual melhor forma de sincronizar imagens dentre as navegações, até que seja concluído o cadastro/alteração do item.

Comment: Só lembrando. Minha pergunta não envolve qualquer tipo de código. Obrigado!

Comment: Sério ? Então por que você adicionou a tag `javascript`, conforme solicitado ? E mais então sua pergunta está ampla e fora do escopo.